# Getting onlick event definition (google extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

is it possible to get what on click function is binded to the element in vanillaJS and reuse that? I want to write google extension and I would need to 'prebind' my onclick function to then element, do some work and the call the original function. Is that possible?

Comment: So far it sounds like you can simply use addEventListener with the third parameter being `true` to add the listener in the capture phase that runs before the normal phase. If you really want to spoof the site's click handler you'll have to do it in [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: Oh seems great. But I came up with another idea. This is how I can intercept ajax call
`(function(send) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(body) {
        console.log(body)
        send.call(this, body);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);` But the problem is I can't recognise what caused that call. I would need to know url or anything that has unique id. Is that possible?

Comment: Intercept `open` instead of (or in addition to) `send` so you will have the url parameter.